# Show that bilinear form is $H^1(0,l)$-elliptic/coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let
$$a(u,v) := \int_0^l \partial u(x) \partial v(x) + cu(x)v(x)\, \mathrm{d}x + \alpha u(l)v(l)$$
Show that $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ is $H^1(0,l)$-elliptic if either $c > 0$ or $\alpha > 0$.

My attempt at a solution:

The case where $\alpha$ is $0$ is straightforward. I am stuck on the $c =0$ and $\alpha > 0$ case. I need to show that 
\begin{align}
\int_0^l (\partial v(x))^2 \, \mathrm{d}x + \alpha u(l)v(l) \ge \int^l_0 (\partial v(x))^2 + v(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align}
 I've been comparing the terms of the $||v||_{H^1}$ term by term to the bilinear form - clearly, $a(v,v) \ge \int_0^l (\partial v(x))^2$, so that term is fine. But I can't figure out why $a(v,v) \ge c_0 \int_0^lv(x)^2$. The only estimate that I found to work with is that $|u(l)| \le 2l^{1/2} ||\partial u||_{L^2} + 2l^{-1/2}||u||_{L^2}$, and that's not getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of [Friedrich's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs%27_inequality), which, when specialized to your case, states that
\begin{align}
\left\|u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2} \le l^{2}\left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2}
\end{align}

Obviously,
\begin{align}
a(u,u) &:= \int_{0}^{l} \partial u \partial u \, \mathrm{d}x + \alpha u(l)^{2} \ge \left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2}. 
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2} 
&= \left(1 - \frac{1}{l^{2}} \right)\left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2}  + \frac{1}{l^{2}}\left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2} \\
&\ge \frac{1}{l^{2}}\left\| u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2}  + \frac{1}{l^{2}}\left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2}  - \frac{1}{l^{2}}\left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2} \\
\left(1+\frac{1}{l^2}\right)\left\|\partial u\right\|_{L^{2}[0,l]}^{2} 
&\ge \frac{1}{l^{2}}\left\|u\right\|_{H^{1}[0,l]}^{2} 
\end{align}
so that $a(u,u) \ge \frac{1}{1+l^2}\left\|u\right\|_{H^{1}[0,l]}^{2}$.

I have a proof of Friedrich's inequality sitting around if you want it; but it seemed off-topic here . . .

Comment: Thank you! I have not seen Friedrich's inequality before, but I have seen Poincare's. I tried working through the proof with Poincare's instead of Friedrich's, and I believe that it works the same... the constant is less specific, but that is fine by me. Would that work to do, or am I missing something that would prevent me from applying Poincare's?

Comment: Poincare's inequality seem just fine to me.

Comment: But we only have $u \in H^1(0,l)$, not $H^1_0(0,l)$, so Friedrich's/Poincare's inequality doesn't apply.

Comment: @riem: Whoops! You're completely right. I'll try to patch this up in a few days.